# Swup.js + Oxygen (wp) - Not loading correct site?

Tags: javascript, ajax, wordpress, swup

I'm trying to implement [Swup.js](https://swup.js.org/) into a site in Oxygen for Wordpress. For some reason, the correct version of the site is not loaded when I use Swup.

For some reason, the correct version of the site is not loaded when I click the links. It seems to load a responsive version of the site instead. Here is the link to the page: https://testswup.kastanjeskolan.nu/  If you go to Our Services, you get one version of the page. But if you update/reload, you get the correct version. [Here is a video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UZYHiP1fKNFDWdgH4sVyShsRgpO9aJdK/view?usp=sharing) to show what I mean.

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Swup JS only loads what's in the Swup element/Swup body. It keeps the same header or  of the page for all the pages.

Oxygen builder generates CSS files for each page created. If you check page source of the *Proucts* page on your site, you'll see the CSS file for products page generated by Oxygen. (pointed in the image below).
[image: CSS file for prodcuts page]

Now when you move from *Products* page to *Services* page, this CSS file remains as is because it is in the  section of site. And the CSS file for Services page is also **not loaded** because the  is not refreshed, because that's how Swup works.

---

### Solutions

1. Solution for this is having a single CSS file which contains all the CSS for all the pages. But not sure if that would be output by Oxygen builder.
2. Use the [Head Plugin](https://swup.js.org/plugins/head-plugin) provided by Swup. Although not sure if it will work correctly with Oxygen Builder.